# Does the position of implicits matter?

Tags: idris

Is there a difference between

```
foo: {len : _} -> Int -> Vect len Int
```

and

```
foo: Int -> {len : _} -> Vect len Int
```

and similar for data constructors, type constructors etc? Sometimes I find my code compiles with implicits in one position but not in another, and I'm not quite clear on why.

Comment: If your code runs differently with implicits in different places, then I would assume it probably does matter

Answer (score 3):

It would matter if you use the value of one implicit in the type of another like:

```
x : {n : Nat} -> {ts : Vect n Type} -> HVect ts
```

In this case `n` must be before `ts`.

Answer (score 1):

One minor difference: it appears implicits are only in scope if preceding arguments are also in scope. For example, in

```
foo : {len : _} -> Int -> Vect len Int
foo = ?rhs -- len IS in scope here
```

while

```
foo : Int -> {len : _} -> Vect len Int
foo = ?rhs -- len is NOT in scope here
```

and

```
foo : Int -> {len : _} -> Vect len Int
foo x = ?rhs -- len IS in scope here
```